# Presenting any Social Media Login View Controllers causes navigation bar to collapse into/behind status bar

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationbar, presentviewcontroller

Experiencing a pretty strange issue with navigation bar when presenting any social media login view controller.

The navigation bar seems to lose its top layout constraint boundary or something and moves up behind the status bar.

In image you can see the navigation bar moved up behind status bar. This view is not meant to have a navigation bar, its just been added to illustrate the problem.

After this view controller is dismissed, navigation bar is shown and its shown behind the status bar. If i put the app into background and open again then the navigation bar resets to its correct position.

Other info to note:

- Parent Controller has navigation bar.
- Child Controller added does not have a navigation bar.
- When child controller is dismissed and removed. Parent controller unhides the navigation bar.

Any ideas or solutions will be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I believe this is happening because whenever the parent loses focus, the navigation controller moves with it. If you're presenting like this you should be using a modal view or a full-screen view.

Comment: @xTwisteDx I have a full view parent controller which contains a full view child controller with the nav bar hidden. Child controller is presenting the google sign in controller. With google sign in i have no options to determine how it is presented.

Child controller contains a view inset like 12 px from each edge to have the floating view controller effect.